# How to call QgisInterface class in a plugin

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm trying to access the `QgsLayerTreeView` class through the `QgisInterface` class in the python plugin I have created. Ultimately I want to be able to return the selected node (group or layer) from the `QgsLayerTree`.

The issue I'm running into is I don't know how to call it. Most information suggests to use `iface` as a way to access the interface but it's not recognised when called from the plugin (works fine from the python console in QGIS).

Is there any other way to create an instance of the `QgisInterface` class? Or is there a way I can import the `iface` class to work in my plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your plugins `__init__()` method should take the interface as an argument on instantiation, probably under the name `iface`.

If it is stored as instance variable there via a line like

```
self.iface = iface
```

you can then use it in any of your plugin's methods via `self.iface`.