# Call and Run PyQGIS script by plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I wrote a code that work well in console python, an example:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsLayerTreeGroup, QgsLayerTreeLayer, QgsLayerTree
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QVariant, QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, 

QCoreApplication
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QAction, QIcon, QFileDialog, QProgressDialog, QProgressBar, QShortcut, QKeySequence
from osgeo import ogr
from shutil import copyfile

from urllib.request import urlopen
import re

import processing, glob, os, time


newLyrName1 = '1_PdR da controllare 4326'
newLyrName2 = '2_PdR attivi da controllare 4326'

#definisco il progressivo delle operazioni
m=0
n=0

#Definisco il nome dei campi da utilizzare come variabili
fieldX = 'X_COORD'
fieldY = 'Y_COORD'

m=m+1
n=0
#creo un popup che richiede una risposta
msgBOX = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(iface.mainWindow(), '',#titolo
    str(m) + " - Importare i PdR da file excel?", #messaggi
    QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes, QtGui.QMessageBox.No) #pulsanti
```

And I saved it in a file called "importXLS.py" stored in a folder "script".
Then I built a plugin with a custom toolbar.
[image]

Now, what I want to do is that when I press a button it call and execute a pyqgis script inside a console python but, for now, I can only open a console python but I cannot execute nothing inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking around, I found this post: [How to call QgisInterface class in a plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/388870/how-to-call-qgisinterface-class-in-a-plugin?rq=1).
It helps me having and idea: first I changed `iface` before call and run a script:

[image]

Then anytime, when the script is called and run by QGis, if on console python QGis advised me that it cannot run the script because a function is not defined:

[image]

I will add it at the start of the code that I call by plugin script:

[image]

In that way I can run python console scripts by QGis plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line to the imports of the plugin file.

```
from pathlib import Path # import section
```

Then use the next lines in the code that will run when the button is clicked.

```
python_file_path = "c:/test/importXLS.py"
exec(Path(python_file_path ).read_text())
```

Comment: Excuse me because I'm newbie... What you mean to "import section"? Above the first class? o under def __init__(self, iface):? I tried above first class, but nothin happens...

Comment: Top lines of a Python file are known as import section containing the words of `import` and `from`

Comment: As you suggested I  added the <from pathlib import Path> in the first part of the code, before class declaration. then I wrote the code under run definition with right path. Restarting QGis it don't give me and error pressing on button, but it not start the <QtGui.QMessageBox.question> so I cannot understad if something gone wrong, what is, and where

Comment: Ok... now I know what's going wrong. Your code works well, but the code on the file path must have the syntax of qgis plugin. The problem is that the cose is writted for python console syntax and, because is very long and complex, I cannot translate it. So there's a way to use it as i do in python console?